# Can't connect custom action with the custom reducer react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-admin

8.4 of react-admin. I've been trying to implement a custom action that connects with the custom reducer but so far nothing has worked.
I've Implemented this part of the guide in the official documentation for the action side https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.8/Actions.html#querying-the-api-with-fetch and this for the reducer https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.8/Admin.html#customreducers. The problem stems from that I can only use useUpdate method which sends update request, instead of a get without **connecting** to the reducer and there is no clear explanation of how I can chain those two things together. I also tried using an older way of dispatching actions, but still didn't work. Please help I've been trying this for 2 weeks now. Nothing gets updates and the redux store stays the same.

component

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQueryWithStore({
        type: 'getList',
        resource: 'goals',
        action: "GET_USER_GOALS",
        payload: { pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 10 }, sort: { field: "a-z", order: "ABC" }, filter: {} }
    });
```

reducer

```
export default (previousState = 0, { type, payload }) => {
    console.log(type)
    if (type === 'GET_USER_GOALS') {
        return payload.rate;
    }
    return previousState;
}
```

I even wrote a custom action
but it says that **"Cannot read property 'update' of undefined"** which isn't supported in the newer version I guess.

```
import { UPDATE } from 'react-admin';

export const UPDATE_PAGE = 'GET_USER_GOALS';
export const setGoals = (id, data) => {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_PAGE,
        payload: { id, data: { ...data, is_updated: true } },
        meta: { fetch: UPDATE, resource: 'goals' },
    }
};
```

admin

```html
 <Admin
        locale="en"
        customReducers={{ userGoals: userGaolsReducer }}
        loginPage={LoginPage}
        authProvider={authProvider}
        dataProvider={testProvider}
        i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
        history={history}
        dashboard={Dashboard}
        customSagas={[userGoalsSaga]}
      >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include it in the store.js as well

```
  const reducer = combineReducers({
    admin: adminReducer,
    router: connectRouter(history),
    userDashboardSettings: userGaolsReducer
  });
```